# Make your program USE a gui

Tags: python, user-interface, remote-control

I'd like to write a program able to "use" other programs by taking control of the mouse/keyboard and being able to "see" what's on the screen.

I used [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/) to do something similar, but I had to cheat sometimes because the language is not that powerful, or maybe it's just that I suck and I'm not able to do that much with it :P

So... I need to:

- Take screenshots, then I will compare them to make the program "understand", but it needs to "see"
- Use the mouse: move, click and release, it's simple, isn't it?
- Using the keyboard: pressing some keys, or key combinations, including special keys like <kbd>Alt</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> etc...

How can I do that in python?
Does it works in both linux and windows? (this could be really really cool, but it is not necessary)

Comment: check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032489/how-can-a-program-control-another-program/1032542

Comment: Nick, the answers to that question didn't mention screenshots. However, you could probably automate that part. My guess is that Andrea wants a complete automation package for regression testing.

Comment: If it is really for regression testing, then Andrea is most likely on the wrong path. It's not a good idea to automate GUI testing except in most bizzare circumstances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had some luck with similar tasks using [PyWinAuto](http://pywinauto.openqa.org/).

> pywinauto is a set of python modules
>   to automate the Microsoft Windows GUI.
>   At it's simplest it allows you to send
>   mouse and keyboard actions to windows
>   dialogs and controls.

It also has some support for capturing images of dialogs and such using the Python Imaging Library [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/).

Answer (score 2):

AutoIt is completely capable of doing everything you mentioned.  When I'm wanting to do some automation but use the features of Python, I find it easiest to use [AutoItX](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.autoitscript.com%2Fautoit3%2Fdownloads.shtml&ei=Yk9TSsOsDYnWNfza6fQI&usg=AFQjCNEBCnVe6pRuxIzX_UE4U_3O8SVYOg&sig2=t4kpjNbgspeikHz2SBkIGg) which is a DLL/COM control.

Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151846/get-other-running-processes-window-sizes-in-python/155587#155587) of mine:

```
import win32com.client
oAutoItX = win32com.client.Dispatch( "AutoItX3.Control" )

oAutoItX.Opt("WinTitleMatchMode", 2) #Match text anywhere in a window title

width = oAutoItX.WinGetClientSizeWidth("Firefox")
height = oAutoItX.WinGetClientSizeHeight("Firefox")

print width, height
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [WATSUP](http://www.tizmoi.net/watsup/intro.html) under Windows.

Comment: Do not click this link, it will take you to a virus website

Answer (score 1):

If you are comfortable with pascal, a really powerful keyboard/mouse/screen-reading program is SCAR: http://freddy1990.com/index.php?page=product&name=scar  It can do OCR, bitmap finding, color finding, etc.  It's often used for automating online games, but it can be used for any situation where you want to simulate a human reading the screen and giving input.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the Windows (only) [Input API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310(VS.85).aspx) to write a VNC-like remote-control application in the past.  It lets you fake keyboard and mouse input nicely at a system level (ie not just posting events to a single application).

If you're trying to do any sort of automated testing of whole systems at the GUI level, [this excellent USENIX paper](http://www.usenix.org/event/usenix05/tech/freenix/full_papers/zeldovich/zeldovich_html/index.html) describing automated responsiveness testing is a must-read.