# Delphi - Pause all playing sounds to play a specific sound on my app

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

How to pause all playing sounds (Windows media palyer or another palyer) to play a specific sound in my application and then return to play the previous paused sound.

That is, if you want a sound is being played on a sound player like windows media player, my program pause this sound to play a specific sound, and after finishing the specific sound to play back the sound was paused. Can someone help me?

My delphi version is 2010. Thanks.

Comment: Suppose you managed to pull this off and I do the same from my app while your app is playing its sound - what would happen then? Put another way: this is probably not possible.

Comment: Why shouldn't it be possible, @500? Certain smartphones can do it. I don't know whether Windows supports anything like it, but there's no inherent reason that such a feature couldn't exist. I can think of three ways it could work with multiple programs: A second program could either pause the first program, and then resume just that program when finished, leaving the first one to resume all other programs once *it's* finished; or a second program could be forced to wait for a "pause mutex" before playing; or a second program could just fail to play at all.

Comment: Sorry my friends thought it was not something so hard for someone so experienced in programming. I just needed to pause the song playing on windows media player, play a sound in my app and then continue the song on windows media player to the point where she had paused. If anyone can help me I thank you in advance!

Comment: You only need to pause Windows Media Player?

Comment: Yeah... Basically what I need is to pause the music on windows media player, to be able to play a sound in my application and then replay the song in windows media player from the point where it was paused.

Comment: +1 I think this is a great question and don't see why all the fuss, other than OP asking for someone to basically "Share da codez"

Comment: I'm assuming this shall also include things such as web browsers streaming audio, etc. I've asked a similar (but not duplicate) question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126287/how-to-mute-the-sound-of-my-application

Comment: Doesn't Skype also do this during an incoming call? I also heard a rumor that Skype was built in Delphi...

Comment: How annoying if you manage to pull this off. Don't install your software on any machine that I work on. Thanks :)

Comment: @WoutervanNifterick: I agree wholeheartedly, possibly with the exception of Skype. Even then I'd prefer the volume would be toned down instead of the replay being paused. After all, I may be listening to a radio station.

Comment: Good morning people, not necessarily pause the sound in wmp, mitigate would be enough, since the message of my application could be heard clearly, because it is important notices. Can anyone help me?

Comment: No one? Look if this can help me help =):

I can do what I'm saying using winamp api, I can also do this in wndows vista + + using "setvolumeapp." However I need to do it with windows media player.

Comment: Your question says you want to pause "a sound player like Windows Media Player," which means you wish to be able to pause *any* arbitrary sound player. In your comments, you seem to suggest you *only* need to handle Windows Media Player. That distinction is important. Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: That's right Mr. Rob Kennedy, I just need to pause (or volume down) the windows media player. And later replay paused. I believe it is using  FindWindow or api, etc.. Can you help me?

Comment: Skype probably uses the default communication device, in which case it's the **system** that reduces the sounds of *console* and *multimedia* applications according to **user configuration** in sound cpl's *communications* tab.

Answer (score 2):

You did not specify which version of Windows you are targeting. It makes a big difference if you want to control audio per application.

In Windows 7, you can control the volume per application (well.. stream).

Applications that use ASIO cannot be controlled like this, but if you only care about Windows Media Player that shouldn't be a problem.
[image: Mixer]

You can control the volume (or mute) of streams via the Core Audio API. `IAudioEndpointVolume` or `ISimpleAudioVolume` interfaces.

However, I would't recommend messing with mixer volumes.

Windows has a mechanism built in that does what you want. It's called `ducking` or `stream attenuation`, which is meant to lower/mute the volume of all non-communication audio streams when a "communication" stream starts.

In the Windows multimedia control panel (Mmsys.cpl) you can configure the default behavior via on the communications tab:

[image: Settings]

You'll have to find the default communication device, and play audio through that.

This unit here can help you to find it:
http://code.google.com/p/mfpack-media-foundation/source/browse/trunk/MFPACK/CoreAudio/MMDeviceAPI/MMDeviceApi.pas

From here on I'm not 100% if ducking occurs automatically when you play audio or not. 
I didn't try it myself, but hopefully this guides you in the right direction.
Let me know if you book any results.

ps: 
If I were you I'd look a bit deeper into [mfpack](http://code.google.com/p/mfpack-media-foundation), because it seems to be a useful library for this kind of stuff. 
I see that there are 3 comitters for that project (maxcmx, factoryx.code, and peter larson). I'm sure they can tell you how to accomplish your goal the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Searching on google I found a windows xp application that does exactly what I need, it is called an **IndieVolume** per-application volume control ([link here](http://www.indievolume.com/)) for Windows XP. I'll test it and see how it works, in the worst case I have to do a workaround so you can do what I want. NO but if someone has a better idea, I'm always willing to listen, or rather read on ...