# Looking to create a bot for an online java based game

Tags: c++, opencv, bots

I am currently doing research on how I am going to do this.

I need a program to read the screen of my computer(pixels, edges, etc) and an answer that I think might work is opencv. However everything I look into about opencv reads from a video camera and not from a computer screen. Is it possible to record the screen and use it in the same fashion that I see video cameras being used in opencv?

If so can anyone point me to some reading on this? So far I havent found any examples that apply to what I am looking for

EDIT: I am not looking for anybody to write code for me. Im simply asking if it is possible to use the screen as a video feed for opencv. I am not familiar with opencv nor have I ever used it before.

Comment: 1) Cheating is bad  2) Why not just read the gamestate from the game's memory?

Comment: second that. Parsing the entire screen to get some information, already available somewhere in the memory is a really bad idea. If the game is written is java, you can freely modify its code, and recompile it. The best method is to write a loader in java, witch manages the running game.

Comment: See my answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032489/how-can-a-program-control-another-program/1032530#1032530

Comment: They somehow detect that you are modifying the client/reading variables and the account that was used gets banned. The only existing bot that does not get your account banned only reads the screen through pixels etc. I know its not a pretty way to do it but it seems like the only way.

Answer (score 1):

Does the system have to use OpenCV and C++? I know that Java can do this very easily using its built it Robot class the code being:

```
 try {
    Robot robot = new Robot();
Rectangle captureSize = new Rectangle(0, 0, 500, 500);
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = robot.createScreenCapture(captureSize);
}
catch(AWTException e) {
    System.err.println("Error");
}
```

If you really want to use OpenCV and C++ you could connect to them via JNI but this would probably be making life harder than it needs to be.