# (Programming) See contents of a window/form

Tags: linux, windows, winforms, user-interface, winapi

Is there a way to create a program(preferably C/C++, but in the end, I need the idea not the code) that "sees" other windows/forms?
Something that can realize Chrome/Word is open and how many buttons it has etc.? Maybe have the software virtually "push" a button on another program.

Just point me towards the general direction please. What to read about and where to study more.

I hope I was clear enough.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are looking for [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Having a program "see" and interact with another program is similar to how many video game bots work; one common method of designing said bots is using image recognition (Pixel by Pixel) to match something on the screen to the likeness of something in memory.

This question goes into further details on bots and how they're designed and function:
[How can a program control another program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032489/how-can-a-program-control-another-program)